# Можно ли использовать OpenCV FaceRecognizer со значениями с разных веб-камер?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Суть моей задачи заключается в том, чтобы подтвердить, что стоящий перед веб-камерой человек тот, за котого он себя выдает.

Я использую JavaCV обертку для OpenCV. Наиболее вменяемого результата у меня получилось добиться только с LBPHFaceRecognizer. Для вырезки лиц я использую CascadeClassifier, он работаем идеально. Для тренировки FaceRecognizer я сделал три своих фотографии, тренирую ими LBPHFaceRecognizer.

Далее начинаю читать кадры с камеры, вырезать лица через CascadeClassifier и проверять их через LBPHFaceRecognizer. Значения в среднем плавают от 40 до 80, и я никак не могу понять, как сделать тот порог, при котором можно было бы сказать, что это тот или не тот человек. Проблема в том, что разница между моим лицом и лицом моего друга слшиком мала, а если я начинаю использовать данные с разных веб-камер, то мой друг в некоторых случаях оказывается похожим на меня еще больше, чем я сам (с человеческой точки зрения мы совсем не похожи).

Когда я использую FisherFaceRecognizer или EigenFaceRecognizer, то результаты вообще кажутся случайными.

```
                        LBPHFaceRecognizer      EigenFaceRecognizer     FisherFaceRecognizer
me_other_cam.jpg        0(57.88068288364994)    0(3229.4422758656347)   2(814.0787739217529)
me_other_cam_70.jpg     0(63.99033263154956)    0(4926.722681568904)    2(1053.061899364804)
my_face.jpg             1(43.07787265588305)    1(1201.3009600199732)   1(871.1282700104315)
my_face_1.jpg           1(59.74185494758271)    1(2181.752998255585)    0(526.7529177018118)
my_face_phonecam.jpg    0(39.17574071277724)    1(1945.76519819016)     0(699.3950738318528)
obama_face.jpg          0(78.17124639956032)    1(961.4037158625265)    0(635.6915648292386)
sanya.jpg               0(64.28323191473481)    0(1829.7706721567006)   0(860.2100341293506)
```

Я пробовал увеличивать число своих фотографий, которыми я обучаю распознаватель, но это не давало результатов. Вообще мне бы желательно иметь только одну фотографию, которой я бы обучал распознаватель.

Что я упускаю? Какую-то нормализацию изображений? Или из коробки OpenCV распознаватель лиц не работает так как я хочу, и необходимо много подполниетльного кода?

Comment: LBPHFaceRecognizer работает лучше всего, так как он может работать и при небольшом кол-ве эталонных изображений. Нормализовывать изображение все же нужно: делам его серым, обрезаем все кроме глаз, губ и рта, делаем тонкомпенсацию, делаем сглаживание. Да результат стал лучше, теперь он вырос до 19 с 43. Но про прежнему много проблем, на результат влияет практически любая мелочь, от освещения до незначительной тени на лице, которую человеческий взгляд даже не воспринимает с первого взгляда. Получается, что данный подход/алгоритм не годится для боевых условий? Или я им неправильно пользуюсь?